# Why are median transaction fees so much higher now (in october 2017) than a year ago?

Tags: transaction-fees

Now that segwit transactions are consistently making up [10% of each block](http://segwit.party/charts/) and the witness section is making up more than 6% of the block, I'm a little confused by why median transaction fees are still high. A year ago, there were about [230k transactions/day](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactions.html#1y) and now there are about 260k transactions/day - just a 13% increase. But fees are [up 1400%](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-median_transaction_fee.html#1y) since a year ago.

What's causing fees to remain high even tho we've increased capacity by 6% (and rising) and only have 13% more transactions? Are people still falling for bad fee prediction algorithms? Is there an increased demand for quickly-confirming transactions?

Answer (score 2):

The relation between `average transaction size` and `average transaction fee` is not linear.

> Are people still falling for bad fee prediction algorithms?

There are no `good` prediction algorithms here. Think about 110 people waiting for  a bus, but the bus has only 100 seats.

> Is there an increased demand for quickly-confirming transactions?

I don't think so. Most of users do not care at all about transaction fees while their capital grows.

Comment: I guess this might help explain it: https://blockchain.info/charts/avg-block-size?timespan=1year . A year ago, we simply weren't hitting the max block size. Now we're regularly bumping up against it.