# Who pays miners fees?

Tags: transaction-fees

I was under the impression that miners earned coin from the blockchain (creator/owner/pool) or "Created" the coin they are paid??
But I see now that fees are involved to buy/sell/transfer.

For example I had $21 dollars left in in my wallet and wanted to transfer it
to GDAX, I was not able to because of insufficient funds to transfer.

Can someone explain how this works. (seems very expensive)

Comment: What do you mean, "how this works"? What exactly do you want to know?  (Have you browsed the other [tag:transaction-fees] questions on this site?)  If your question is simply "is it really this expensive", then the answer is yes, it really is.  See also https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54464/is-a-20-fee-normal-right-now/54465#54465, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60615/why-are-median-transaction-fees-so-much-higher-now-in-october-2017-than-a-year.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple, you pay the miner a fee as part of your transaction to encourage the miners to include that transaction in a block. Block space is limited so larger transactions in size rather than value have to pay more fee.